# my javascript is making multiple calls to functions that should only be getting called once

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using asp.net and javascript to create a CRUD web page for a table.  When I first run the code everything works fine -- I can update/insert/delete and the page refreshes with the new results. If I do a second update/insert/delete, for some reason the call to get the updated data is being called and the results are being shown twice. If I execute the code a third time, it calls the refresh data function three times. And so on and so on.  I'm afraid I don't know enough about javascript and ajax to understand what I've done wrong to cause this and am hoping somebody more experienced may be able to spot it.

Below is my javascript..getData() is the function that retrieves the data from my database.  In this function are onclick events for the insert/update/deletes. They each call the same function - altRec(), and pass in the action (update/insert/delete). altRec in turn formats a modal and displays it, and alters the submit button to call the update/insert/delete function.  On success whichever function selected calls the get_data() function to get the updated dataset.

```
var pageID = 45;
var det;

$(document).ready(function () {
console.log('docReady');

getData();
});

function getData() {
console.log('getData');

$('#actScores').empty();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url: "WebServices/ccr.asmx/getUserACTScores",
    data: JSON.stringify({ pageID: pageID }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (results) {
        var lastPersonID = '';
        det = results.d;

        for (var i = 0; i < det.length; i++) {
            if (det[i].personID != lastPersonID) {
                var stud = "<tr>"
                    + "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success' onclick=\"altRec('" + 
i + "', 'insert');\">Insert</button></td>"
                    + "<td>" + det[i].lastName + ", " + det[i].firstName + "</td>"
                    + "<td class='text-center'>" + det[i].SSID + "</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>"

                $("#actScores").append(stud);
            }

            var rec = "<tr>"
                + "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning' onclick=\"altRec('" + i + 
"', 'modify');\">Update</button>&nbsp;<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' 
onclick=\"altRec('" + i + "', 'delete');\">Delete</button></td>"
                + "<td></td>"
                + "<td></td>"
                + "<td class='text-center'>" + det[i].actDate + "</td>"
                + "<td class='text-center'>" + det[i].actComposite + "</td>"
                + "<td class='text-center'>" + det[i].actEnglish + "</td>"
                + "<td class='text-center'>" + det[i].actMath + "</td>"
                + "<td class='text-center'>" + det[i].actReading + "</td>"
                + "<td class='text-center'>" + det[i].actScience + "</td>"
                + "</tr>"

            $("#actScores").append(rec);
            lastPersonID = det[i].personID;
        }
    }
})
}

function searchTableColumn() {
console.log('searchTableColumn');

var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("actScores");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
}

function altRec(idx, action) {
console.log('altRec');

if (action == 'insert') {
    $('#modalTitle').html("Insert New Record");
    $('#modalSSID').html(det[idx].SSID);
    $('#modalStudent').html(det[idx].firstName + " " + det[idx].lastName);
    $('#modelDate').html();
    $('#btnAction').html("Insert");
    $('#btnAction').removeClass("btn-warning");
    $('#btnAction').removeClass("btn-danger");
    $('#btnAction').addClass("btn-success");
    document.getElementById("btnAction").removeEventListener("click", modRec, true);
    document.getElementById("btnAction").removeEventListener("click", delRec, true);
    document.getElementById("btnAction").addEventListener("click", function () {
        saveRec();
    });
} else if (action == 'delete') {
    $('#modalTitle').html("DELETE RECORD");
    $('#modalSSID').html(det[idx].SSID);
    $('#modalStudent').html(det[idx].firstName + " " + det[idx].lastName);
    $('#modalInputDate').val(formatDate(det[idx].actDate)); 
    $('#modalInputComposite').val(det[idx].actComposite);
    $('#modalInputEnglish').val(det[idx].actEnglish);
    $('#modalInputMath').val(det[idx].actMath);
    $('#modalInputReading').val(det[idx].actReading);
    $('#modalInputScience').val(det[idx].actScience);
    $('#btnAction').html("DELETE");
    $('#btnAction').removeClass("btn-warning");
    $('#btnAction').removeClass("btn-success");
    $('#btnAction').addClass("btn-danger");
    document.getElementById("btnAction").removeEventListener("click", modRec, true);
    document.getElementById("btnAction").removeEventListener("click", saveRec, true);
    document.getElementById("btnAction").addEventListener("click", function () {
        delRec();
    });
} else if (action == 'modify') {
    $('#modalTitle').html("Update Record");
    $('#modalSSID').html(det[idx].SSID);
    $('#modalStudent').html(det[idx].firstName + " " + det[idx].lastName);
    $('#modalInputDate').val(formatDate(det[idx].actDate));
    $('#modalInputComposite').val(det[idx].actComposite);
    $('#modalInputEnglish').val(det[idx].actEnglish);
    $('#modalInputMath').val(det[idx].actMath);
    $('#modalInputReading').val(det[idx].actReading);
    $('#modalInputScience').val(det[idx].actScience);
    $('#btnAction').html("Update");
    $('#btnAction').removeClass("btn-success");
    $('#btnAction').removeClass("btn-danger");
    $('#btnAction').addClass("btn-warning");
    document.getElementById("btnAction").removeEventListener("click", saveRec, true);
    document.getElementById("btnAction").removeEventListener("click", delRec, true);
    document.getElementById("btnAction").addEventListener("click", function () {
        modRec();
    });
}

$('#modalPersonID').html(det[idx].personID);
$('#modalRec').modal('show');
}

function saveRec() {
console.log('saveRec');

var parmSave = {
    personID: $('#modalPersonID').html(),
    testDate: $('#modalInputDate').val(),
    compScore: $('#modalInputComposite').val(),
    englishScore: $('#modalInputEnglish').val(),
    mathScore: $('#modalInputMath').val(),
    readingScore: $('#modalInputReading').val(),
    scienceScore: $('#modalInputScience').val()
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url: "WebServices/ccr.asmx/insertUserACTScore",
    data: JSON.stringify(parmSave),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (results) {
        var retVal = results; 

        getData();

        $('#modalRec').modal('hide');
    }
})
}

function delRec() {
console.log('delRec');

var parmSave = {
    personID: $('#modalPersonID').html(),
    testDate: $('#modalInputDate').val(),
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url: "WebServices/ccr.asmx/deleteUserACTScore",
    data: JSON.stringify(parmSave),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (results) {
        var retVal = results;

        getData();

        $('#modalRec').modal('hide');
    }
})
}

function modRec() {
console.log('modRec');

var parmSave = {
    personID: $('#modalPersonID').html(),
    testDate: $('#modalInputDate').val(),
    compScore: $('#modalInputComposite').val(),
    englishScore: $('#modalInputEnglish').val(),
    mathScore: $('#modalInputMath').val(),
    readingScore: $('#modalInputReading').val(),
    scienceScore: $('#modalInputScience').val()
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url: "WebServices/ccr.asmx/updateUserACTScore",
    data: JSON.stringify(parmSave),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (results) {
        var retVal = results;

        getData();

        $('#modalRec').modal('hide');
    }
})
}

function formatDate(date) {
console.log('formatDate');

var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

Finally, here's a screenshot with the console log, so you can see the call stream:

[image]

Comment: I think you need to clear the table before create new elements, because there's already the first studend loaded, and then you call the service and add two more studends from the service, student 1 and 2

Comment: every time you click same button it binds more events.

Comment: Are you supporting a legacy app or creating a new one? If you a working on something new it is time to move on from this jQuery nightmare. Your time would be way better spend learning a modern framework like Angular, Vue or React.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!  The problem was in my function altRec(), specifically where I was trying to remove the EventListener function from the other button calls, I guess my syntax wasn't correct because they were not being removed and every time that function got called it just added another event listener -- pretty much as @epascarello pointed out in the comments.  After doing some research I discovered that you can now add an EventListener and pass a parameter of "once: true", and it will run once and remove itself.  I removed the lines of code that were manually removing the events and added that option, and everything works great now:

```
        document.getElementById("btnAction").addEventListener("click", function () {
        saveRec();
    }, { once: true });
```